# Make spaces match in two strings

Tags: java, string

I have got a file with a lot of two pairs of string, namely a bilingual file. On some entries the target strings don't contain number of space equal to src after ":"

E.g.

```
src= Job %1$s: Bad record length at tape record number / block number: %2$s adddd: %3$s
tgt= Travail %1$s : longueur d'enregistrement incorrecte dans le numéro d'enregistrement / de bloc :%2$s de la bande adddd: %3$s.
```

I need the `:%2$s` to be `: %2$s`

Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you need to get done? Could you give a more comprehensive and complete example?

Comment: @aioobe  I need to match number of spaces in src after a colon to target. E.g. if src has 3 spaces after the second colon ":" the target should have 3 spaces after the second colon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String src = "abc :  def";   // two spaces after colon.
        String tgt = "ghi :   jkl";  // three spaces after colon.

        Pattern spaces = Pattern.compile("([^:]*:)(\\s*)(.*)");

        Matcher mSrc = spaces.matcher(src);
        Matcher mTgt = spaces.matcher(tgt);

        mSrc.matches();
        mTgt.matches();

        System.out.println("Spaces in src: " + mSrc.group(2).length());
        System.out.println("Spaces in tgt: " + mTgt.group(2).length());

        System.out.println("Target with src's number of spaces: " +
                           mTgt.group(1) + mSrc.group(2) + mTgt.group(3));
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Spaces in src: 2
Spaces in tgt: 3
Target with src's number of spaces: ghi :  jkl
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
src = src.replaceAll(":%", ": %")
```

Comment: What I need is to match number of space available to src. for example if src msg has 3 spaces target should have 3 spaces, if source has 2 target should have 2